# MVC, ASP.NET application, link to nowhere and non-standard tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For an MVC, ASP.NET application, how can I use an HTML Helper to generate a link such the following -

```
<a class="myClass" gatag="myGatag" href="#">Link to nowhere!</a>
```

In some cases in the application, I want to have a link that doesn't go anywhere, that is why I have the `href="#"`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with `@Html.ActionLink("","",new {class="myClass"})` by overriding the default behaviour. But if you dont want it to fire you need to write script to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MVC 4 this works (probably 2 and 3, but I don't have a project using those)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link to nowhere!", "", "", new { href="#", @class="myClass", gatag="myGatag" })
```

Renders as

```
<a class="myClass" gatag="myGatag" href="#">Link to nowhere!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done using custom html helper.

Typically for these kind of extensions, I will create a folder called "Infrastructure" inside the MVC web application and create a static class "HtmlHelperExtensions" and place the below method.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text)
{
    TagBuilder aTag = new TagBuilder("a");

    aTag.MergeAttribute("gatag", "myGatag");
    aTag.MergeAttribute("href", "#");
    aTag.AddCssClass("myClass");

    aTag.SetInnerText(text);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(aTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

It can be called from View using

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link to nowhere!")
```

Comment: Thanks Sundeep! Could you give me an example of how this would be called?